# Why aren't Enumerators in Ruby (2.0 +) lazy by default?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

Why don't Ruby `Enumerator` behave like `Enumerator::Lazy` by default?

Is there any case where someone would want use a non-lazy `Enumerator`?

**Edited:**

A comment to backward compatibility answers below, explaining why I'm not yet convinced:

Say we had added these 'breaking' changes to Ruby 2.0.0, which is a major version, you would test your code (especially if you're going to production) thoroughly before making the switch, no?

**Edit#2**

I suspected it has to do with efficiency (let me know if anything is wrong), so I did the following benchmark: (of course there are places where lazy is better. this is to demonstrate, potentially, why Ruby is not using lazy all the time?)

```
require 'fruity'
require 'prime'

compare do
  lazy { 
    g = Prime::EratosthenesGenerator.new; 1000.times { g.lazy.take(100).to_a } 
  }
  diligent { 
    g = Prime::EratosthenesGenerator.new; 1000.times { g.take(100).to_a } 
  }
end
```

I get the following: (maybe due to the calling of `.lazy` method instead of using `Enumerator::Lazy` from the beginning?)

```
diligent is faster than lazy by 19.999999999999996% ± 1.0%
```

Comment: Good question! +1.. BTW I am not aware of

Comment: Haha :-) Waiting for good answers!

Comment: @ArupRakshit Are you using a client that notifies you when ruby questions are asked?

Comment: No.... there is question comes with tagged as ruby, browser displays as 1,2,3,... like that..

Comment: Haha.. Cool :-) .. I was asking because you're so fast!

Comment: @ArupRakshit is that a browser plugin? ;) that you created?

Comment: @uDaY No Its a Firefox browser, no plug-in..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make laziness the default would be a [*breaking change*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breaking_change) for any code that expects/relies on side-effects.

Any previous usage of Enumerator would need to be examined and tested. The "safest"/"sane" approach is simply to *keep* the non-lazy behavior as the default - while providing a Lazy alternative.

Some fundamental/previous design decisions are not so easily discarded; Enumerators are supported as far back as Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Do you have any example where using `Enumerator::Lazy` (or an enhanced version thereof) would break the code?

Comment: @Abdo I don't need to provide an example for this claim (although it is trivial to create a contrived example). Rather, to show that it would be a non-breaking API change, one would need to look at all existing Ruby code that uses Enumerator to show that it is *not* the case that someone's wonderful [production] code would break.

Comment: Say we had added these 'breaking' changes to Ruby 2.0.0, which is a major version, you would test your code (especially if you're going to production) thoroughly before making the switch, no?

Comment: @Abdo Touché. The major 2.0 release *could* have declared it a breaking-change and made it so. There may be discussions archived on the ML as to why this was not done at the time.

Comment: Cool... So you're saying it was a matter of "choice" and `Enumerable::Lazy` is perfectly fine to replace `Enumerable` in the future?

Comment: @Abdo Excluding breaking changes (and the historical reasons for such), I know of no reasons why it *couldn't*. I rely on lazy-enumeration features all the time in multiple languages. However, [this post](http://railsware.com/blog/2012/03/13/ruby-2-0-enumerablelazy/) indicates that there may performance-related implementation issues, at least at the time (I'm not sure what has been addressed).

Comment: @Abdo Java 8 (and Scala, generally) also requires an explicit stream ("lazy") operation; some rational for a separate steam ("lazy" enumerator) are [discussed here](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2013/05/lazy-sequences-implementation-for-java-8.html). On the other hand, more functional languages (and even .NET via the default Enumerable implementation) are lazy-by-default.

Comment: Haha.. Now I'm wondering why it's used implicitly in some languages in explicitly in others and whether there are effectiveness concerns.. Time to benchmark :-)

Answer (score 2):

Probably for compatibility. Lazy enumerators were introduced recently, and many code depend on enumerators being non-lazy.